# Displaying the joints in an image with kinect depth

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

Displaying the joints in an image with depth sensor kinect?
For example, the image below:

[image]

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Kinect SDK are you using?

Comment: @VitoShadow version 1.8